# Spring: object is not an instance of declaring class

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

i wrote simple Spring app
with config in xml:

```
  <bean id="flyingDelegate" class="pl.marcindebski.spring.aspects.LowFlyingKnight"></bean>

  <aop:config>
    <aop:aspect ref="usageTracking">
        <aop:declare-parents
            types-matching="pl.marcindebski.spring.aspects.Knight+"
            implement-interface="pl.marcindebski.spring.aspects.FlyingKnight"
            delegate-ref="flyingDelegate"
            />
    </aop:aspect>
  </aop:config>
```

and when i run app with code:

```
    Knight knight = context.getBean(Knight.class);

    if (knight instanceof FlyingKnight)
    {
        FlyingKnight flyingKnight =(FlyingKnight)knight;                                                
        flyingKnight.fly();
    }

context.close();
```

on the line with `flyingKnight.fly();`  i got:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.aop.AopInvocationException: AOP configuration seems to be invalid: tried calling method [public abstract void pl.marcindebski.spring.aspects.FlyingKnight.fly()] on target [pl.marcindebski.spring.aspects.BraveKnight@5e82df6a]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
```

QUESTIONS:

1)the class `LowFlyingKnight` implements `fly()` method from `FlyingKnight` interface. Why the Spring consider `Knight` is `FlyingKnight` (`knight instanceof FlyingKnight`) is true, but it's fail on calling `fly()` method.

2) the class BraveKnight is an implementation of Knight interface, so why `knight instanceof BraveKnight` is false, but `knight.embarkOnQuest` execute implementation from BraveKnight

---

main class -> App.java

```
package pl.marcindebski.spring.aspects;

import org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FileSystemXmlApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(
                new String[] {
                        "E:/dev/eclipse-workspaces/1-aspects/flying.xml",
                        "E:/dev/eclipse-workspaces/1-aspects/minstrel.xml" });

        Knight braveKnight = context.getBean(Knight.class);
        if (braveKnight instanceof BraveKnight) { // FALSE!
            braveKnight.embarkOnQuest();
        }

        braveKnight.embarkOnQuest(); // Working!

        if (braveKnight instanceof FlyingKnight) // true
        {
            FlyingKnight flyingKnight = (FlyingKnight) braveKnight;
            flyingKnight.fly();// why its not working ?
        }

        context.close();
    }

}
```

aspects:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">


  <bean id="flyingDelegate" class="pl.marcindebski.spring.aspects.LowFlyingKnight"></bean>

  <aop:config>
    <aop:aspect>
        <aop:declare-parents
            types-matching="pl.marcindebski.spring.aspects.Knight+"
            implement-interface="pl.marcindebski.spring.aspects.FlyingKnight"
            delegate-ref="flyingDelegate"
            />
    </aop:aspect>
  </aop:config>

</beans>
```

beans definitions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

  <bean id="knight" class="pl.marcindebski.spring.aspects.BraveKnight">
    <constructor-arg ref="quest" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="quest" class="pl.marcindebski.spring.aspects.SlayDragonQuest">
    <constructor-arg value="#{T(System).out}" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="minstrel" class="pl.marcindebski.spring.aspects.Minstrel">
    <constructor-arg value="#{T(System).out}" />
  </bean>

  <aop:config>
    <aop:aspect ref="minstrel">
      <aop:pointcut id="embark"
          expression="execution(* *.embarkOnQuest(..))"/>

      <aop:before pointcut-ref="embark" 
          method="singBeforeQuest"/>

      <aop:after pointcut-ref="embark" 
          method="singAfterQuest"/>
    </aop:aspect>
  </aop:config>

</beans>
```

Comment: How does BraveKnight fit into all this?

Comment: BraveKnight is a bean, implementation of Knight interface :   <bean id="knight" class="pl.marcindebski.spring.aspects.BraveKnight"></bean>

Comment: Hmmm. the exception reads that it is telling the BraveKnight to fly. I have no idea why BraveKnight is considered a FlyingKnight, though. You might be fetching the wrong Knight entirely?

Comment: BraveKnight is a implementation of Knight(from java code) and it has added interface FlyingKnight (as a Spring Introduction).

Comment: can you show how other beans are defined

Comment: i just added main class and configuration files